# How to get per-testcase scoping for dependency injected objects in Python?

Tags: python, unittest2

I'm using [python-inject](http://code.google.com/p/python-inject/), python 2.6 (with unittest2).

We have classes to test that use injection, and test-cases which also use the same values. We currently use inject.appscope, to "singletonize" the values. Otherwise they're instantiated per user.

```
import inject

class A(object):
    '''shared data between many parts'''
    ...

class Foo(object):
    '''uses a to do stuff'''

    a = inject.attr('a', A)

    def bar(self):
        self.a.doStuff()

class TestFoo(TestCase):
    a = inject.attr('a', A)

    def setUp(self):
        self.foo = Foo()

    def testBar(self):
        self.foo.bar()
        self.assertTrue(self.a.stuffWasDone())
        self.assertFalse(self.a.stuffWasDoneTwice())

    def testBarTwice(self):
        self.foo.bar()
        self.foo.bar()
        self.assertTrue(self.a.stuffWasDoneTwice())


injector = inject.Injector()
injector.bind(A, scope=inject.appscope)
inject.register(injector)

runTests()
```

Ideally, I'd like to reset A after each test run, to avoid cross-contamination.
(Currently do something like A.reset() in tearDown()..)

`inject.reqscope` supports something like this (a locally scoped set of instances), but I don't really know where to call `register()` & `unregister()` (which resets the injection objet cache). Ot's too late in `setUp()` and `tearDown()`, since Foo.a may already be called in `Foo.__init__()` for each of them.

Any ideas on how to do this, or should I use a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setUp` and `tearDown` to register/unregister the scope, treating each test method invocation as a new "request".

With the following changes your sample unit tests pass:

```
class TestFoo(unittest2.TestCase):

    a = inject.attr('a', A)

    def __init__(self, *n, **kw):
        unittest2.TestCase.__init__(self, *n, **kw)
        self.unit_scope = inject.reqscope

    def setUp(self):
        self.foo = Foo()
        self.unit_scope.register()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.unit_scope.unregister()

    ...
```

And bind your `A` instance using `inject.reqscope`:

```
injector = inject.Injector()
injector.bind(A, scope=inject.reqscope)
```

Comment: I tried something like that, because it seemed the most intuitive solution, but it seemed like the register() call was made too late for things to work properly. I'll have a go at it again.

Comment: Well, this worked excellently. I must've missed some detail in my own attempt. Thanks for getting everything correct!

Comment: Cool I'm glad it was helpful! The order of operations caused by `Inject`-ing classes can be tricky to trace.